Should I install a vapor barrier on top of the insulation inside my shed?
I have a 12x16 shed with shingles, tar paper, radiant barrier on roof and walls, house wrap and have vents up in both gable ends. There are no eaves or ridge vents. I will be using this shed as a work space as well as storage. There will be no plumbing.
I am in Zone 4 and wish to insulate the roof and walls. I am thinking about using R13 faced in the walls and still undecided on what insulation should be used under the roof. Should it be R13 as well (2x4 rafters) or should I use a foam board, etc?  Should I use a vapor barrier over the insulation? I will probably be using plywood for the wallboard.
I will be installing some type of A/C, but it will not be used daily and only during the warm/hot months. I have one 2x3 single pane window, ingress/egress 6' double doors. No fume storage. Walls are 8'.

You haven't asked a specific question.   You say you will be working in the shed. Will it be air-conditioned?  Does it have a window?  What are the ingress/egress points?  Are things that may give off fumes stored there?

Sorry about that.  Thanks for responding.  The question is should I use a vapor barrier over the insulation before putting up the walls. Will probably use plywood.  Yes on the A/C and one 2 x 3 single pane window, ingress/egress 6' double doors.  No fume storage.  Ceiling is 8'.

Please edit and add that info to your question.

Faced insulation is a vapour barrier, so you do not add a second barrier over it.  You also only use one layer of faced insulation if using two or more layers.  The face insulation faces the inside of the building.

I still don't understand your question. I've revised to clean it up and made your title an actual question. Please revise further to explain what "the insulation" is on the ceiling. You don't mention that, but you seem to be asking specifically about it. See [ask] and take the [tour].
